# Why do websockets and HTTP conflict?

Tags: http, websocket, port, conflict

I am trying to use the same port on the same host.

```
Websocket URL
ws://aaa.bbb.cc.ddd:eeee/ws


HTTP URL
http://aaa.bbb.cc.ddd:eeee/docs
```

But when I open the "http://aaa.bbb.cc.ddd:eeee/docs" page, I get this error message.

```
Failed to open a WebSocket connection: invalid Connection header: keep-alive.
You cannot access a WebSocket server directly with a browser. You need a WebSocket client.
```

Http does not work. But, websocket is connected normally.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

### The WebSocket protocol is not the HTTP protocol.

Although the WebSocket protocol does initiate a new connection using an HTTP request, it quickly upgrades the connection to full WebSocket (which requires a `Connection: upgrade` header in the initial request, not `Connection: keep-alive`).

You can't use a vanilla web browser to directly communicate with a WebSocket URL, as such a browser doesn't know how to finish the upgrade, let alone process any WebSocket packets.  So, you must use a valid WebSocket client (such as the [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) that modern browsers expose to client-side scripting).

Comment: I think your blurring some lines here. Websocket is a part of HTTP protocol, and the "Websocket client" as your calling it is a valid part of the HTTP client loading the page. They don't just exist in the same space.

Comment: @JSON "*Websocket is a part of HTTP protocol*" - no, it is not. It is a completely separate and unrelated protocol. It just happens to *use* HTTP (but is not limited to just HTTP) to initiate its handshake, but after that is finished, it moves away from HTTP completely. There is no mention of WebSocket in the HTTP protocol RFCs

Comment: you are correct :bow: